# using hibernation to transfer computer state from one computer to another

Tags: hibernate

I had an idea and I'm wondering how possible it is.
If I were to hibernate a computer, then remove it's hard drive and put it into another computer with identical hardware, would it be able to resume?

If that is possible, how impracticable would it be for the OS maker to separate the hardware specific drivers and such so that computer state could be transferred from one machine to another just by transferring the hibernation file and maybe any updated files on the hard drive.

Comment: I'm guessing it wouldnt' work perfectly because of the various hardware IDs of the base hardware which would then change.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this works fine.

Practically the devil is in the details: "Identical hardware" is not really identical, with the Ethernet MAC being one of the more obvious examples. This boils down to the only "identical" machine to wake up on often being the one that you went to sleep at.

That said, I regularily move an SSD with a hibernation image between two machines (Ubuntu 16.04, home and work) and things work fine - I did have to manually set up both ethernet connections and a few minor details.